# How to combine two results of CompletableFuture when one depends on another?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, completable-future

There are 2 services:

1. Service1 returns list of ids1;
2. Service2 returns list of ids2 by id1:

How can I group result by `id1 -> [id2, id2, id2, ...]` using `CompletableFuture`?
I was thinking to put it all to the HashMap but I don't understand how to pass ids1 to the second Future. I was thinking of using `thenCombine(ids1Future, (v1, v2) -> {...})`, but it seems quite ugly to me.
Are there any "best practices" to do it?

Here is not async way:

```
Map<ID1, List<ID2>> idsMap = new HashMap();
      
List<IDS1> ids1List = service1.service.find();
      
for (ID1 id1: IDS1) {
    List<IDS2> ids2List = service2.findById(id1);
    idsMap.put(id1, ids2List);
}
service2.process(idsMap);
```

Trying to do it async:

```
CompletableFuture<List<IDS1>> ids1Future
        = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service.find());

ids1Future.thenApply((ids1) -> {
    CompletableFuture<List<IDS2>> listFutureIds2
            = ids1.stream().map(id1
                    -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()
                    -> service2.getById(id1)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    CompletableFuture<Void> allFuturesDone
            = CompletableFuture.allOf(
                    listFutureIds2.toArray(
                            new CompletableFuture[listFutureIds2.size()]));
    allFuturesDone.thenApply(v
            -> list.stream()
                    .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                    .collect(toList()));

});
```

Comment: What you need in your case is a fork/join implementation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html

Comment: how about your provide some code that matches your description first? `CompletableFuture<List<IDS1>> listFutureIds2` is supposed to be `CompletableFuture<List<IDS2>> listFutureIds2`?

Comment: I edited the code. I hope it's more clear now what exactly I mean.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to use Fork/Join to convert a list of chars to a list of strings, where each string is a replication of N times of the char. You can adjust this example to your case.

I hope that this is what you are looking for.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ForkJoinExample {
    
    public static class RepeatTask extends RecursiveTask<List<String>> {

        private final List<Character> chars;
        private final int repeatCount;

        public RepeatTask(List<Character> chars, int repeatCount) {
            this.chars = chars;
            this.repeatCount = repeatCount;
        }

        public RepeatTask(Character c, int repeatCount) {
            this.chars = List.of(c);
            this.repeatCount = repeatCount;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<String> compute() {
            if (chars.size() > 1) {
                ForkJoinTask.invokeAll(chars.stream().map(c -> new RepeatTask(c, repeatCount)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
                return ForkJoinTask.invokeAll(chars.stream().map(c -> new RepeatTask(c, repeatCount)).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                        .stream()
                        .map(ForkJoinTask::join)
                        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
            return List.of(String.valueOf(chars.get(0)).repeat(Math.max(0, repeatCount)));
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ForkJoinPool commonPool = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();
        RepeatTask task = new RepeatTask(List.of('a', 'b', 'c'), 4);
        commonPool.execute(task);
        System.out.println(task.join());
    }
}
```

The result is this one: `[aaaa, bbbb, cccc]`

Comment: it's helpful, but is there a way to do it using CompletableFuture?

Comment: howdoes this answer the question?

Comment: @Eugene this is a classical case of fork/join. You have a list of elements, you split the work for each element and after that you join the results. Obviously, the problem can be solved in many ways, one of this is your solution. One advantage of my solution is that, if the service2 will be able to return a list of result for many id's (for example to optimize network traffic) then this solution is still applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you correctly, so here it is:

```
   CompletableFuture<List<IDS1>> ids1Future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(service::find);

   CompletableFuture<Map<IDS1, List<IDS2>>> map = ids1Future.thenApply(listIDS1 -> {
        List<Entry<IDS1, CompletableFuture<List<IDS2>>>> list =
            listIDS1
                .stream()
                .map(ids1 -> new SimpleEntry<>(ids1, CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service2.getById(ids1))))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return list.stream()
                   .map(entry -> new SimpleEntry<>(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().join()))
                   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));

    });

    Map<IDS1, List<IDS2>> result = map.join();
```

Comment: it seems like. I'm gonna check it out. Will be back soon)

Comment: @poena_cullei did that help?